# Openstack Kolla Ansible reconfigure all compute node to enable provider network

Tags: openstack

May I ask how to reconfigure all compute node to enable provider network in Kolla Ansible openstack?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What's the problem have you met? PLZ show in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, `openstack` will [support](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/overview.html#networking-option-1-provider-networks) to create **[provider network](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/launch-instance-networks-provider.html)** while `kolla-ansible deploy` success.

Because it enable the relevant composes default in **all-in-one** or **multinode** file, something like this:

```
# Neutron
[neutron-server:children]
control

[neutron-dhcp-agent:children]
neutron

[neutron-l3-agent:children]
neutron
```

While `neutron-l3-agent` enable default, you could also create **[Self-service network](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/launch-instance-networks-selfservice.html)** not only **Provider networks**.

IIUC, you could create the `provider network` and launch instance with this network, like the documentation describe:

```
$ openstack network create --share --external \
  --provider-physical-network provider \
  --provider-network-type flat provider
```

One more thing, your network infrastructure (such as switch or router) should configure correctly at first while you using it.